# angular ControlValueAccessor check if bound using ngModel

Tags: angular, custom-controls

I have a custom input element which implements ControlValueAccessor.  However my control should also be usable using just [value]='valuetoshow' without using ngModel.  For example it should be usable in either of the following manners

```
<mycontrl [(ngModel)="customValue"] />
```

or

```
<mycontrl [value]="customValue" />
```

I got the first option figured out and that works fine using ControlValueAccessor, however how do I handle the second situation.  Basically from the control how do I check if its bound using `ngModel`

Plus, Internally this control uses a textBox.

```
 <input type="text" />.
```

Now I need to check if my custom control is bound using `ngModel` and if so then bind the inner textBox using `ngModel` and if not just set the value.  What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

in constructor you can try get the NgControl, if not exist, it's a standalone input

```
constructor(@Optional() control:NgControl){
    if (!control)
       console.log("I have no [(ngModel)] or [formControl]")
}
```